# Caret : train() function - Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, gbm

I'm trying to predict binary variable (level of spending) using caret in R.

My dataset have 415 000 rows and 30 features (**all features are factor**). I need to compare performances of severals machine learning algorithms.

```
#Convert factor level   
levels(tableRFM_train$niveau_Depense) <- c("A","B")
#Sample rows and select sub-sample
tableRFM_train <-tableRFM_train[sample(1:nrow(tableRFM_train),size=45000),]
```

**Random Forest**

When I try to tune mtry parameters with size of sub-sample > 45000 rows I have this error: (if size <  : I don't have it)

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1    NA's   :1   
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
De plus : Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

I don't understand ... I try few things to solved problem :

- remove variable with missing values (missing values are grouped in factor level) : sum(is.na(tableRFM_train))=0
- remove unbalanced variables and variables with variance is zero

`paramgrid <- data.frame(mtry=seq(1,3,by=1))
    cl <- makeCluster(6)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    rfopt <-train(niveau_Depense~.,data=tableRFM_train,method="rf",
        trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=10,search="grid",classProbs=T,
                  tuneGrid=paramgrid,prox=TRUE,allowParallel=TRUE)#,na.remove=T
    stopCluster(cl)`

When I test to tune **GBM** with sub sample of 200 000 rows I have the same error with NA's   :1    NA's   :1 for Accuracy and Kappa. When I tune **SVM** with sub sample > 45 000 I have also this error.

I don't have any missing values in target and others variables ..

The result of **str(tableRFM_train)** :

```
'data.frame':   276664 obs. of  28 variables:
 $ q_pm_p_1           : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 21 ]","[ 22 - 32 ]",..: 1 4 3 3 2 3 1 1 4 1 ...
 $ q_pm_p_2           : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 23 ]","[ 24 - 40 ]",..: 2 4 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 1 ...
 $ q_pm_p_3           : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 25 ]","[ 26 - 43 ]",..: 3 4 4 2 4 3 3 4 2 2 ...
 $ q_ir_p_1           : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 6 - 10 ]","[ 11 - 16 ]",..: 2 1 2 1 4 1 4 1 2 4 ...
 $ q_ir_p_2           : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 0 - 6 ]","[ 7 - 14 ]",..: 2 1 2 2 4 4 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ q_ir_p_3           : Factor w/ 3 levels "[ 0 - 7 ]","[ 8 - 16 ]",..: 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 3 1 ...
 $ q_evol_pm_p_3_p_2  : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ -100 - -40 ]",..: 1 3 3 2 3 1 1 3 1 1 ...
 $ q_evol_pm_p_2_p_1  : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ -100 - -25 ]",..: 1 3 4 3 3 1 2 3 4 2 ...
 $ q_ecart_ir_p_3_p_2 : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ -20 - -2 ]",..: 1 2 4 2 4 4 1 2 1 4 ...
 $ q_ecart_ir_p_2_p_1 : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ -14 - -1 ]",..: 3 4 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ q_age              : Factor w/ 12 levels "[18-24]","[25-29]",..: 10 3 3 12 12 8 3 9 12 10 ...
 $ q_anciennete       : Factor w/ 3 levels "[ 0 - 4 ]","[ 5 - 5 ]",..: 2 1 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ q_attachement_mag  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Faible","Fort": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ q_diversification  : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 3 ]","[ 4 - 6 ]",..: 4 4 2 4 2 1 4 1 2 4 ...
 $ q_indice_coordo    : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 0 - 4 ]","[ 5 - 5 ]",..: 3 3 1 1 2 3 2 1 3 3 ...
 $ q_recence_p_1      : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 0 - 11 ]","[ 12 - 30 ]",..: 4 1 2 3 2 2 1 4 3 1 ...
 $ q_recence_p_2      : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 0 - 12 ]","[ 13 - 45 ]",..: 2 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ q_recence_p_3      : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 0 - 14 ]","[ 15 - 47 ]",..: 2 4 4 2 4 2 2 4 1 3 ...
 $ q_frequence_p_1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 2 ]","[ 3 - 5 ]",..: 2 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 2 4 ...
 $ q_frequence_p_2    : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 3 ]","[ 4 - 7 ]",..: 1 4 1 1 2 2 2 4 1 2 ...
 $ q_frequence_p_3    : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 3 ]","[ 4 - 7 ]",..: 1 4 4 1 4 1 2 4 2 1 ...
 $ q_presence_p_1     : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 2 ]","[ 3 - 4 ]",..: 2 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 2 4 ...
 $ q_presence_p_2     : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 3 ]","[ 4 - 5 ]",..: 1 4 1 1 3 3 2 4 1 2 ...
 $ q_presence_p_3     : Factor w/ 4 levels "[ 1 - 3 ]","[ 4 - 6 ]",..: 1 4 4 1 4 1 2 4 2 1 ...
 $ q_delai_reachat_p_1: Factor w/ 4 levels "0-13","14-24",..: 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 2 ...
 $ q_delai_reachat_p_2: Factor w/ 5 levels "0-14","15-26",..: 5 4 5 5 3 2 1 4 5 1 ...
 $ q_delai_reachat_p_3: Factor w/ 5 levels "0-13","14-24",..: 5 4 4 5 4 5 3 4 3 5 ...
 $ niveau_Depense     : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

***R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) and latest Caret Version***

Comment: First off you should check for missing values, other than that remove variables with 0 variance, etc.

Comment: When I use sum(is.na(tableRFM_train)) it returns 0. All my variables are factor and I removed unbalanced variables. 
I try to sample row of my train dataset in order to avoid factor of my target variable are sorted (all factor A at the beginning and B at the end)

Comment: share `str` of your data.

Comment: I think [ 1 - 2 ] is not allowed as factor level as it has special characters. Try reclassifying labels into character or numeric.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. When I tune parameter with sub sample of 30 000 rows I don't have this error. I can't tune parameter with size of my train sample > 45 000 rows.  Furthermore, before the discretization of my variables (all my variables were quantitative) I had the same error ...

Comment: I think this is due to sampling. one of the variable after the sampling only has a single level due to which this error arises.

Comment: No When I check summary after sampling all my variables are severals factors. But I think I found out where is the problem. If I remove this option : **prox=T** the error doesn't appaear at the moment. What is the interest of this option ?